# Bootstrap collapse on <ol> always causes scroll to top

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Can anybody advise why bootstrap collapse causes the scrollbar to reset to the top whenever collapse is triggered?

To test:

Go to: http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/140/, scroll part-way down the page and click any of the buttons. You'll be sent back to the top but based on the documentation, this isn't default behaviour.

HTML

```
<div class="list">
<div class="listheader">
  <a class="btn listname" href="#">Colors</a>
</div>
<ol class="things">
  <li><a href="#">White</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
<div class="list">
<div class="listheader">
  <a class="btn listname" href="#">Colors</a>
</div>
<ol class="things">
  <li><a href="#">White</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
<div class="list">
<div class="listheader">
  <a class="btn listname" href="#">Colors</a>
</div>
<ol class="things">
  <li><a href="#">White</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
<div class="list">
<div class="listheader">
  <a class="btn listname" href="#">Colors</a>
</div>
<ol class="things">
  <li><a href="#">White</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
<div class="list">
<div class="listheader">
  <a class="btn listname" href="#">Colors</a>
</div>
<ol class="things">
  <li><a href="#">White</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
<div class="list">
<div class="listheader">
  <a class="btn listname" href="#">Colors</a>
</div>
<ol class="things">
  <li><a href="#">White</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
<div class="list">
<div class="listheader">
  <a class="btn listname" href="#">Colors</a>
</div>
<ol class="things">
  <li><a href="#">White</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
<div class="list">
<div class="listheader">
  <a class="btn listname" href="#">Colors</a>
</div>
<ol class="things">
  <li><a href="#">White</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Blue</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Red</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Green</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
</ol>
</div>
```

JS

```
/*$('.things').collapse("hide");*/

$(".listname:not(.disabled)").livequery('click', function(event) {
    $(this).parents('.list').find('.things').collapse("toggle");
    $("#listview, #thingview, #allview").removeClass('active');
});
```

(Livequery also included)

Comment: To prevent scrolling add onclick="return false;" to your links

Comment: Ah - this is the equivalent to Diodeus' solution below, right? Is there any reason why this option is better? I've used preventDefault() successfully in the past so am inclined to stick with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

..to your script to cancel the click on the current href (a hash mark)